# Inserting newlines in SQL request causes error 1136

Tags: php, mysql

**Environment**

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Apache 2.4.52
PHP 7.4
MySQL 5.7.42

**Context**

I am writing an SQL request inside a PHP program. Everything else apart the piece of code `$this->db->prepare(...);` remains exactly the same in my program.

Here is my SQL table.

[image: The SQL table]

**Problem**

When the request is written as follow, everything works fine, my data gets inserted into the database.

```
$prep = $this->db->prepare('
    INSERT INTO brochure2(firmid, name, cat, presentation, stages_recrutements, message, pdg, creation_year, implantation, effectifs, chiffre_affaire, website, mail, phone)
    VALUES (:firmid, :name, :cat, :presentation, :stages_recrutements, :message, :pdg, :creation_year, :implantation, :effectifs, :chiffre_affaire, :website, :mail, :phone)
    ');

$prep->bindParam(':firmid', $firmid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prep->bindParam(':name', $data['name']);
$prep->bindParam(':cat', $data['cat'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prep->bindParam(':presentation', $data['presentation']);
$prep->bindParam(':stages_recrutements', $data['stages_recrutements']);
$prep->bindParam(':message', $data['message']);
$prep->bindParam(':pdg', $data['pdg']);
$prep->bindParam(':creation_year', $data['creation_year']);
$prep->bindParam(':implantation', $data['implantation']);
$prep->bindParam(':effectifs', $data['effectifs']);
$prep->bindParam(':chiffre_affaire', $data['chiffre_affaire']);
$prep->bindParam(':website', $data['website']);
$prep->bindParam(':mail', $data['mail']);
$prep->bindParam(':phone', $data['phone']);

$prep->execute();
```

But the following fails, even though it is basically the same with additional newlines and spaces.

```
$prep = $this->db->prepare('
    INSERT INTO brochure2 (
        firmid,
        name,
        cat,
        presentation,
        stages_recrutements,
        message,
        pdg,
        creation_year,
        implantation,
        effectifs,
        chiffre_affaire,
        website,
        mail,
        phone
    ) VALUES (
        :firmid,
        :name,
        :cat,
        :presentation,
        :stages_recrutements,
        :message,
        :pdg,
        :creation_year,
        :implantation,
        :effectifs,
        :chiffre_affaire,
        :website,
        :mail,
        :phone
    )');

$prep->bindParam(':firmid', $firmid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prep->bindParam(':name', $data['name']);
$prep->bindParam(':cat', $data['cat'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prep->bindParam(':presentation', $data['presentation']);
$prep->bindParam(':stages_recrutements', $data['stages_recrutements']);
$prep->bindParam(':message', $data['message']);
$prep->bindParam(':pdg', $data['pdg']);
$prep->bindParam(':creation_year', $data['creation_year']);
$prep->bindParam(':implantation', $data['implantation']);
$prep->bindParam(':effectifs', $data['effectifs']);
$prep->bindParam(':chiffre_affaire', $data['chiffre_affaire']);
$prep->bindParam(':website', $data['website']);
$prep->bindParam(':mail', $data['mail']);
$prep->bindParam(':phone', $data['phone']);

$prep->execute();
```

Precisely, I get the following error: `[Sun Jun 25 11:24:48.567644 2023] [php7:warn] [pid 5092] [client 127.0.0.1:32956] PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` .

**Conclusion**

In both cases I expect the data to be inserted successfully into the database, and thus $prep->execute(); returning True. But the first case is successful and the second one fails.

I don't understand why because I thaught SQL was a whitespace insensitive language.

I have also double checked that there are as many columns as values in the request, and as many values as bindParam() in my PHP, so I find this error weird.

Thanks for your answers :)